# What happens when I click the like button on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, web

My thought process on this would be that when I click the like button, there would be a post request made from client to server to create a 'like' for the user to message. When I open the chrome console, no request is being made. What is happening that allows the like count to increase and to register as the user making the like. I assuming that there is also some front end framework that might be handling this client request.

Comment: They use Ajax/websockets i think

Comment: *"When I open the chrome console, no request is being made."* - Really? When I open the Chrome console and check the Network tab I see that a request *is* being made. Seems to be an Ajax POST request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course a request is being made, and you are correct--it is indeed a http POST. The problem you are having is that you are looking in the wrong place. The console displays only what is logged to it as your browser executes some code. It also likes to display things when stuff goes bad. The tab you will be interested in viewing is the "Network" tab. It is here you will be able to view all outgoing and incoming requests recorded by your browser. Facebook has a lot of moving parts, so specifically you can click the sub tab in the Network area titled XHR. This will show you all the Http Requests and preview the actual payload. I just clicked a like and saw that when I do, a request by the name of "bz" is generated and wraps a json object that looks like this:

```
{__ar: 1, payload: null, bootloadable: {}, ixData: {}, lid: "6313242218513768168"}
```

Give it a try and see yourself!